# negative Vds in SMPS!

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply

[image]

Hi,
I am designed a full bridge SMPS, like the above schematic.
But when I measure the switch node voltage (I put voltage probe across Q2), I see when the mosfet is on, the voltage across it is -1 volt!!! As I know, the voltage should be Rds(on)*IQ and it is positive, now how does it possible to be negative???
[image: ti]

Comment: It's an isolated SMPS so which ground is the other side of your voltage probe?

Comment: the probe is connected to drain Q2 and its ground to source of Q2

Comment: If your inductor current is still flowing from source to drain you'll have negative voltage across your FET.